PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 16): Holly Jolly Cryptic Word Tapestry
This puzzle is part of the Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2024. The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 100 reputation.< Previous Door Next Door >
This puzzle follows a similar pattern to this previous puzzle.  I have decided to call this type of puzzle a Word Tapestry, since it weaves together the solutions to the various clues.

The answers to each of the following clues share all of the letters of the final solution.  In addition, each clue's answer contains one more letter, which is one of the letters in the final solution.  Combine the additional letter from each answer to make a word, which will also contain all the letters shared between answers.  That word is your solution.

Example:

Answer 1:  HATH  (additional: H, shared: HAT)
Answer 2:  A HAT (additional: A, shared: HAT)
Answer 3:  THAT  (additional: T, shared: HAT)

Final solution: HAT

Note: these clues are cryptic clues; each one contains both wordplay and definition.  Unlike traditional cryptic clues, the answer won't necessarily be a common or well-known phrase.  To make up for this, there is further wordplay (as described above) linking the various answers, so they should still be reasonably solvable.

The clues

Connect reindeer to the sleigh without the leader: Dasher's third, Cupid's first; then force take off as first restlessness departs.
As their rite regularly, concubines have asked Santa more, primarily for cleavage.
Basically, Santa can't immigrate; he alternately has initial authorization, fraudulent second passports -- finally damages Christmas spirit.
It's crazy: Holiday Special starts getting ungracious at heart; film ultimately leads to intolerance of the force's dark side.
Before the beginnings of holiday revelries, young woman with company picks the wrong actor for personnel management.
Santa Claus initially holds parliament.  At the end, after starting to map ice with deer, goes to a meteorologist's record of foggy places.
At first, Mrs. Santa is having crippling, splitting migraines -- after rapid TIA, starts keeling over -- seems like the splitting in two of a streetcar.
"If tech heads, even, are also home at Christmas..." -- heartless slogan of a militant anti-Apple activist, perhaps?
Final cautions from Helsinki: don't research Santa's exotic memorabilia for gifts: A list that includes a 1965 Ford Mustang, a Tesla Roadster, and The Heat.


The clue answers are as follows:

 1. ITCH S[C]RAMS
 2. SHIRT C[H]ASM
 3. SCARS MI[R]TH
 4. SITH RAC[I]SM
 5. MISCA[S]TS HR
 6. MIST CHAR[T]S
 7. TRAM SCHIS[M]
 8. I TRASH M[A]CS
 9. SMITH'S CAR[S]

All of these are made from the letters of the word...

 ...CHRISTMAS, with one letter of the target word CHRISTMAS added in the mix each time, spelling out the answer in order in square brackets above.

The cryptic wordplay for each clue can be explained as follows. The definition in each clue is emphasised in bold.

 1. Connect reindeer to the sleigh without the leader: Dasher's third, Cupid's first; then force take off as first restlessness departs.
ITCH SCRAMS = (-h)ITCH + (-da)S(her) + C(-upid) + RAM (force) + (-a)S

 2. As their rite regularly, concubines have asked Santa more, primarily for cleavage.
SHIRT CHASM = (-a)S(-t)H(-e)I(-r)R(-i)T(-e) + C(-oncubines) H(-ave) A(-sked) S(-anta) M(-ore)

 3. Basically, Santa can't immigrate; he alternately has initial authorization, fraudulent second passports -- finally damages Christmas spirit.
SCARS MIRTH = S(-anta) C(-an’t) + A(-uthorisation) + (-f)R(-audulent) + (-passport)S + (-i)M(-m)I(-g)R(-a)T(-e)H(-e)

 4. It's crazy: Holiday Special starts getting ungracious at heart; film ultimately leads to intolerance of the force's dark side.
SITH RACISM = ITS* + H(-oliday) + (-ung)RACI(-ous) + S(-pecial) + (-fil)M

 5. Before the beginnings of holiday revelries, young woman with company picks the wrong actor for personnel management.
MISCASTS HR = CAST (company) in MISS (young woman) + H(-oliday) R(-everies)

 6. Santa Claus initially holds parliament. At the end, after starting to map ice with deer, goes to a meteorologist's record of foggy places.
MIST CHARTS = M(-ap) I(-ce) + S(_T)C + HARTS (deer)

 7. At first, Mrs. Santa is having crippling, splitting migraines -- after rapid TIA, starts keeling over -- seems like the splitting in two of a streetcar.
TRAM SCHISM = (M_ S_ I_ H_ C_ S_ M_ A_ R_ T_)<

 8. "If tech heads, even, are also home at Christmas..." -- heartless slogan of a militant anti-Apple activist, perhaps?
I TRASH MACS = I(-f) T(-ech) + (-a)R(-e) A(-l)S(-o) H(-o)M(-e) A(-t) + C(-hristma)S

 9. Final cautions from Helsinki: don't research Santa's exotic memorabilia for gifts: A list that includes a 1965 Ford Mustang, a Tesla Roadster, and The Heat.
SMITH’S CARS = _S _M _I _T _H _S _C _A _R _S


Clue 4 was a mistake on my part.  I accidentally clued the S twice.  Just remove the word "tedious"; it probably makes for a better surface anyway.

For clue 5, the second S should be at the end of the first word in the answer, so that the word is spelled correctly and the tenses in the clue and the answer agree.  "With" here is clueing insertion.

Other than that, well done!  I didn't think it would take long.

@GentlePurpleRain Aha, yes that would make more sense on #5! Will fix now. Thanks.
